# Pi Zero W 1.1 dead wifi

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, pi-zero

About a month or two ago I bought a pi zero w from microcenter for a project but I didn’t start on it until now. I now realize the Pi that I got is one of the defective ones with a bad firmware, so its detected as a pi 2 model b. This means wifi no longer works. Is there any way to fix it or do I have to get a new one?

Comment: *some* people have result with adding `force_board_rev=0x9000c0` to `config.txt` - others not so much, perhaps you need the latest raspbian image or something - although, these people's zero w was identifying as a Pi B Rev 2, not a Pi 2 - try it anyway

Comment: I just read up on the model revision codes, and it seems to me it should be `force_board_rev=0x9000c1` (for revision 1, i.e. 1.1) so try that instead

Comment: Having said all that, the success rate for doing this, is very small - so, probably get a new one - I'd request a **replacement** rather than pay for a new one myself :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! I'll try that later, but yeah they wont take it back. The status LED on it died too.